# criar formulário com tamanho diferente

Tags: html5, css3

boa tarde,

tenho que criar um formulário com diversa linhas e colunas, ate ai normal, queria saber se e possível que uma linha tenha colunas com largura diferente ?

pois a coluna sempre pega a largura do maior tamanho.

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="linha-70">
        <label>Modelo do Equipamento</label>
        <p></p>
      </td>

      <td class="linha-30">
        <label>N° de Serie</label>
        <p></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="linha-70">
          <label>Nome do Cliente</label>
          <p></p>
        </td>

        <td class="linha-30">
          <label>Unidade</label>
          <p></p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td class="linha-100">
            <label>Contato no Cliente</label>
            <p></p>
          </td>
      </tr>

  </table>
```

css:

```
table{
      width: 100%;
    }

    .linha-100{
      width: 100%;
    }

    .linha-70{
      width: 70%;
    }

    .linha-50 {
      width: 50%;
    }

    .linha-30 {
      width: 30%;
    }
```

Comment: Cara por qual causa, motivo ou circunstancia vc está usando tabela para isso? É exigência do sistema ou pode ser de outra forma? Tabela é para dados tabulares, não para montar layout.... Para fazer isso vc deveria usar um Form com labels, inputs e divs

Comment: esse form vai ser puxado pelo Dynamics, então não pode ter framework, nesse caso em especifico nao pode ter input, esse foi o melhor jeito que achei ... caso tenha alguma dica melhor, eu ficaria grato.

Comment: Outra coisa, uma coluna sempre vai ter a mesma largura em todas as linhas. Pelo que posso observar aí, vc está querendo que numa linha tenha uma largura e em outra, outra largura. Isso não é possível.

Comment: O input (tirando o fato de acessibilidade) é o de menos... o maior problema ai é usar tabela para distribuir o layout. Se não vai ser algo enviado por email, com style inline etc, o adequado é usar elementos do próprio form, p, div, span etc... E como o Sam falou, a Coluna sempre terá o valor da menor célula ou seja todas as TDs de uma coluna tarão 30% que é a largura da menor célula

Comment: https://formulario-vyttra.netlify.com/

fiz em BS, mais como disse nao posso usar

Comment: Sim, mas esse forma foi feito com Framework, bootstrap... vc não precisa dele para ter esse mesmo resultado, da para fazer na mão sem maiores problemas! Qual o grau de responsividade que vc quer para isso??

Comment: ate onde me passaram nenhum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom vou dar minhas dicas, mas pode ser que outra pessoa tenha uma solução diferente...

Mas sobre o seu problema repare que eu uma tabela vc não consegue fazer colunas de tamanhos diferentes, pois todas as células (TD) das coluna vão seguir a largura da menor célula. Assim como a altura das células da mesma linha também sempre vão ser iguais, mesmo que uma tenha pouco conteúdo e a outra muito, como vc pode ver nesse exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
}

.linha-100{
  width: 100%;
}

.linha-70{
  width: 70%;
}

.linha-50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.linha-30 {
  width: 30%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="linha-70">
      <label>Modelo do Equipamento</label>
      <p></p>
    </td>

    <td class="linha-50">
      <label>Linha com 50%, mas fica com 30% que é a medida da menor célula da coluna</label>
      <p></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <td class="linha-70">
        <label>Nome do Cliente</label>
        <p></p>
      </td>

      <td class="linha-30">
        <label>Linha com 30% a menor da coluna</label>
        <p></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="linha-100" colspan="2">
          <label>Contato no Cliente</label>
          <p></p>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

---

Agora uma opção de layout usando elementos do `Form` e `FlexBox`. Outra coisa, como seu forme não tem `input` não vejo sentido em usar `label`, mas o fato é que sem esses elementos ele vai ficar completamente "não semântico"

A minha ideia aqui é apenas te mostrar como fazer um grid simples. Deixei as bordas apenas para vc a distribuição dos elementos. Se quiser mais responsivo vc pode fazer um *bracking point* `@madia` e passar todos os `.col-x` para `100%` ai eles ocupam uma linha inteira cada um

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima, conforme vc pode ver é só vc ir criando na classe `.col-x` o tamanho dos campos que vc quer.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.form {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.linha {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
[class^="col-"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .linha {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .col-12,
  .col-9,
  .col-8,
  .col-4,
  .col-3 {
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="linha">
    <div class="col-9">9</div>
    <div class="col-3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="linha">
    <div class="col-8">8</div>
    <div class="col-4">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="linha">
    <div class="col-12">12</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: cara muito obrigado mesmo, vou fazer desse jeito que voce indicou.

Comment: @RoneyBerti como falei é uma opção simples, fácil de adaptar e responsiva, funciona bem do IE10 pra cima, se vc colocar os prefixos direitinho etc... Esse CSS é bem próximo do CSS do Bootstrap, pois os dois são com Flex. Boa sorte ai